# Magento 2 Insert / Move page.main.title inside my custom block

Tags: magento2, php, layout, frontend, xml

I have create a custom xml for Category Page and I need to move the Category Title inside my Block. This is my custom.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top" >
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="my.block" before="breadcrumbs">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">category-static-block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
     </body>
 </page>
```

I try to use this but is not work

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="my.block" before="-"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

Also I have insert this in my custom static block:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Catalog::mtitle.phtml"}}
```

in my mtitle.phtml I have add this code:

```
echo $block->getChildHtml('page.main.title');
```

and in the xml I have add this:

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="my.block" before="-"/>
```

But without success ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use getChildHtml('page.main.title'); to display it in your block "my.block"

```
echo $block->getChildHtml('page.main.title');
```

OR add it after  tag

```
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Title</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you is not a phtml file is a static block

Comment: please check I update my post, I try your idea but no success ...

Comment: you want to change the page title right?
Why do you want to move that title block to a custom block?
Please explain a little more about what you are trying to achive

Comment: is okay thank you